# Is there a way to detect the same event on multiple nodes?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm working on a kind of periodic table, there is an event that ultimately, when you hover the mouse, zooms in a little on said element and shows a little more information, the thing is that it doesn't really do the job very well. tracking could be said, since if the mouse moves a little quickly, or leaves a panel that is on an edge very quickly, it will not detect the exit of the mouse.
This is the code of the animations that should be executed when the mouse enters or exits:

```
public void onScale(int i){
    double currentScaleX = Panes[i].getScaleX();
    double currentScaleY = Panes[i].getScaleY();//stores the current scale
    
    if (currentScaleX == 1.0 && currentScaleY == 1.0) {//verify that said scale is the original (equal to 1)
      

        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50), Symbol[i]);
        translate.setToY(-4);
        translate.playFromStart();//move the symbol up a little

        TranslateTransition tratn = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50), AtomicNumber[i]);
        tratn.setToY(-2);
        tratn.playFromStart();

        TranslateTransition tratm = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50), AtomicMass[i]);
        tratm.setToY(-2);
        tratm.playFromStart();

        TranslateTransition trnm = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50), Name[i]);
        trnm.setToY(3);
        trnm.playFromStart();
        
        AtomicMass[i].setVisible(true);
        OxidationNumber[i].setVisible(true);//makes the atomic mass and oxidation number visible
        
        ScaleTransition scale = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(100), Panes[i]);
        scale.setToX(1.5);
        scale.setToY(1.5);
        scale.playFromStart();
        //The panel is brought to the foreground, (note that this will not affect its position in the childlist unlike the .tofront method)
        Panes[i].setViewOrder(-1.0);
        Panes[i].getParent().setViewOrder(-1.0);
        
        
        
    }
}

public void offScale(int i){
    double currentScaleX = Panes[i].getScaleX();
    double currentScaleY = Panes[i].getScaleY();
    
    if (currentScaleX > 1.0 && currentScaleY > 1.0) {
        
        TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50), Symbol[i]);
        translate.setToY(0);
        translate.playFromStart();

        TranslateTransition tratn = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50), AtomicNumber[i]);
        tratn.setToY(0);
        tratn.playFromStart();

        TranslateTransition tratm = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50), AtomicMass[i]);
        tratm.setToY(0);
        tratm.playFromStart();
        
        TranslateTransition trnm = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(50), Name[i]);
        trnm.setToY(0);
        trnm.playFromStart();

        AtomicMass[i].setVisible(false);
        OxidationNumber[i].setVisible(false);
        
        ScaleTransition scale = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(100), Panes[i]);
        scale.setToX(1.0);
        scale.setToY(1.0);
        scale.playFromStart();
        Panes[i].setViewOrder(0.0);
        Panes[i].getParent().setViewOrder(0.0);
    }
    
}
```

So, do you have any suggestions? I am working with a vector of panes. PS: The way I am using now to make something similar work is by making another method, and which is called later in another where the entire table is initialized.
Methods that call animations:

```
    @FXML
private void MouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
    Pane pane = (Pane) event.getSource();//creates a local variable based on the pane
    onScale(Integer.parseInt(pane.getId()));
    for(int i=1; i<=118; i++){
        offScale(i);
    }
}

@FXML
private void MouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
    Pane pane = (Pane) event.getSource();
    offScale(Integer.parseInt(pane.getId()));
    
}
```

And in part of the initialization method there is a loop, which assigns the events like this:

```
    Panes[i].setOnMouseEntered(this::MouseEntered);
    Panes[i].setOnMouseExited(this::MouseExited);
```

Answer (score 7):

The `MOUSE_ENTERED` and `MOUSE_EXITED` events *should* always be delivered, regardless of the speed you move the mouse or if the mouse leaves the entire window. You have not provided a minimal, complete example, so I cannot be absolutely certain what the issue is. However, I *believe* the problem is that you are creating two *separate* animations for each "direction". That means the "on scale" animation can run in parallel to the "off scale" animation, leading to inconsistent results. It is also strange you are manually registering an event-handler method annotated with `@FXML`, but whether or not that is causing problems depends on the rest of the code you have not shown.

You should use a single animation and manipulate its `rate` property. Not only does this prevent two animations operating in conflict, but it allows the animation to easily switch directions in the middle of playing without messing up the speed of the animation. I also recommend you use a `ParallelTransition` if you want multiple animations to run in parallel, rather than playing each animation individually.

---

## Example

Here is an example demonstrating the suggestions discussed above. There's a GIF at the end showing the output of the code.

The animation is implemented in the `CellAnimation` class nested in the `Cell` class. You'll notice the logic regarding the `viewOrder` of the "cell" is a little more complicated than your current code. Essentially, the logic is:

- Rising cell: View order goes from `0` to `-1` immediately, then to `-2` at the halfway point of the animation.
- Lowering cell: View order goes from `-2` to `-1` at the halfway point of the animation, then it goes to `0` at the end of the animation. Note if the cell was not raised at least halfway then the view order will start at `-1`.

This logic gives the illusion of the rising cell and the lowering cell "passing through" each other at the halfway mark. It also means an animating cell is always rendered above all non-animating cells. In other words, this all makes the animation look more natural.

**Main.java:**

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final int ROWS = 5;
    private static final int COLUMNS = 5;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        var root = new GridPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(30));
        root.setHgap(5);
        root.setVgap(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++) {
                var cell = new Cell(row * COLUMNS + col);
                root.add(cell.getNode(), col, row);
            }
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

**Cell.java:**

```java
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.ParallelTransition;
import javafx.animation.ScaleTransition;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Cell {

    private final StackPane container;
    private final Label indexLabel;
    private final Label moreInfoLabel;

    public Cell(int index) {
        var square = new Rectangle(75, 75, Color.WHITE);
        square.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        square.setStrokeWidth(1);

        indexLabel = new Label(Integer.toString(index));

        moreInfoLabel = new Label("More info!");
        moreInfoLabel.setOpacity(0);

        container = new StackPane(square, indexLabel, moreInfoLabel);

        // must be instantiated after creating nodes
        var animation = new CellAnimation();
        container.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, e -> {
            e.consume();
            animation.playForward();
        });
        container.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, e -> {
            e.consume();
            animation.playBackward();
        });
    }

    public Node getNode() {
        return container;
    }

    private class CellAnimation {

        private static final Duration DURATION = Duration.millis(250);

        private final ParallelTransition transition;

        private boolean rising;
        private boolean changeViewOrder;

        CellAnimation() {
            var toCorner = createToCornerAnimation();
            var fadeInOut = createFadeInAndOutAnimation();
            var scale = createScaleAnimation();
            transition = new ParallelTransition(toCorner, fadeInOut, scale);

            transition.currentTimeProperty().addListener(obs -> {
                if (changeViewOrder) {
                    var currentTime = transition.getCurrentTime();
                    var halfwayTime = transition.getCycleDuration().divide(2);
                    int compare = currentTime.compareTo(halfwayTime);
                    if (rising && compare >= 0) {
                        changeViewOrder = false;
                        container.setViewOrder(-2);
                    } else if (!rising && compare <= 0) {
                        changeViewOrder = false;
                        container.setViewOrder(-1);
                    }
                }
            });

            transition.statusProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                if (newVal == Animation.Status.RUNNING && rising) {
                    container.setViewOrder(-1);
                } else if (newVal == Animation.Status.STOPPED && !rising) {
                    container.setViewOrder(0);
                }
            });
        }

        void playForward() {
            rising = true;
            changeViewOrder = true;

            transition.setRate(1);
            transition.play();
        }

        void playBackward() {
            rising = false;
            changeViewOrder = true;

            transition.setRate(-1);
            transition.play();
        }

        private Animation createToCornerAnimation() {
            var toCorner = new TranslateTransition(DURATION, indexLabel);
            toCorner.setFromX(0);
            toCorner.setFromY(0);
            toCorner.toXProperty().bind(indexLabel.layoutXProperty().negate().add(5));
            toCorner.toYProperty().bind(indexLabel.layoutYProperty().negate().add(5));
            return toCorner;
        }

        private Animation createFadeInAndOutAnimation() {
            var fadeInOut = new FadeTransition(DURATION, moreInfoLabel);
            fadeInOut.setFromValue(0);
            fadeInOut.setToValue(1);
            return fadeInOut;
        }

        private Animation createScaleAnimation() {
            var scale = new ScaleTransition(DURATION, container);
            scale.setFromX(1.0);
            scale.setFromY(1.0);
            scale.setToX(1.5);
            scale.setToY(1.5);
            return scale;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: GIF demonstrating example]

Comment: This might a bit smoother if you set the [view order](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#viewOrderProperty) when playing animations (i.e. when the MouseEnter occurs).  Implemented correctly, it should allow the animated node not to be overlapped by a neighbor node to the right or bottom of the grid.

Comment: A goal of this code was to make it look more like the lowering cell and the rising cell "pass" each other on the way, no matter their relative positions. So, I have `onMouseEntered` set the view order to `-1`, and then the `onFinished` handler set the hovered cell's view order to `-2` while the just-lowered cell's view order is set to `0`. The GIF is actually from a version of the code where the `onMouseExited` handler _also_ set the view order to `-1`. That wasn't quite what I wanted. However, I only changed the code, not the GIF.

Comment: This setup also always has the animating cells rendered above non-animating cells. That said, likely a smoother implementation of the "pass each other" goal would be to change view orders at the mid-point of the animation, rather than at the end.

Comment: Cool, thx for the explanation Slaw, I was only looking at the GIF animation rather than the code, so didn't realize the `viewOrder` differences in the code.  Nice solution and nice explanation.

Comment: Updated answer to implement the "pass each other at halfway mark" and update the GIF to show the current code results.