# Transition time and transform's function do not work in css

Tags: css, javafx, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm building an app using javafx 20.0.1 in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2(Ultimate Edition). Here my css code:

```
.menu_bar {
    -fx-background-color: #FFC7C7;
}

.menu_bar Button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.menu_bar Button:hover {
    -fx-scale-x: 1.2;
    -fx-scale-y: 1.2;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    transition: -fx-scale-x 8s, -fx-scale-y 8s, transform 0.8s;
}
```

The first problem is the transition time (the '8s') is not applied, like when i hover over the buttons, they immediately do the scale transition. And the second problem is the 'transform', no matter what function i use with transform, i always get error like this

```
Nov 12, 2023 10:27:33 PM javafx.css.CssParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:/C:/Users/ADMIN/IdeaProjects/ElearnApp_javafx_Group8/target/classes/Styles/MenuBar.css: Unexpected function 'rotate(' while parsing 'transform' at [13,15]
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: JavaFX CSS does not support transforms or transitions. For the transform, just use `-fx-rotate: 30;`. For the transition, you have to do that in Java by registering listeners on the button’s `hover` property.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77386307/2189127) for similar functionality

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [JavaFX CSS reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

If the CSS feature you are trying to use is not documented there, it is not supported.

As noted by James_D in comments:

> JavaFX CSS does not support transforms or transitions.
>
> For the transform, just use `-fx-rotate: 30;`.
> For the transition, you have to do that in Java by registering listeners on the button’s hover property.
>
> See this answer for similar functionality:
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77386307/2189127